# New to Python looking for some assistance Assistance

Tags: python

For my class we have been instructed to execute the following:

"Create a program called ph.py that determines the acidity or basicity of a solution. It should ask the user to enter a numeric pH value. It should then call a function that accepts the value as a parameter and returns a string indicating that the solution is acidic (pH less than 7), basic (pH greater than 7), or neutral (pH is 7); it should return "invalid" if the value is greater than 14 or less than zero*. Finally, your script should then output the returned string for the user to see."

This is what I was able to come up with:

```
def water_ph() -> object:
    ph: int = int(input("Enter the numeric value for your water: "))
    if ph >= 14 or ph <= 0:
        return f"{ph} invalid"
    elif ph < 7:
        return f"{ph} is acidic"
    elif ph > 7:
        return f"{ph} is basic"
    elif ph == 7:
        return f"{ph} is neutral"


ph = water_ph()
print(ph)
```

Does this look correct? it works I'm just worried I'm not answering the above question correctly.

Comment: The description says your function needs to accept the value as a parameter.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
If you don't know whether your program works, *test it*.  Since you do not have a demonstrable problem, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.  We are not a review or testing service.

Comment: You are not considering decimals: try to input 4.3 (or any decimal value)

Comment: @Gianluca `return f"{ph} is acidic"` happens then !

Comment: @Programmer nope ;-) A decimal value cause "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Comment: @Gianluca of course, how could i forget that !

Answer (score 1):

> call a function that accepts the value as a parameter

> `def water_ph()`

I do not see any arguments in your function declaration.

> returns a string

> `def water_ph() -> object:`

Then why are you declaring the function to return an object ?

> ask the user to enter a numeric pH value. It should then call a function

You are first calling the function and then asking the user for input **iside** this function.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Barryb if this answer helped you please kindly accept and upvote it.